# Struct column is NONE in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have a parquet table in Hive. I make a query:

```
data = spark.sql("""
            SELECT *
            FROM network.flows
            """)
```

Its schema is as follows:

```
root
 |-- msgid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gatewaytimestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- direction: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- deviceid: string (nullable = true)
```

Now I try to look at the data:

```
>>> data.take(1)
[Row(msgid=u'abc', gatewaytimestamp=1243, data=None, deviceid=u'as12']
```

The data column is None for each row, however, if I do the query directly in hive, it is not None. Another point, which might help is: if I make such a query and try to access the data:

```
data = spark.sql("""
            SELECT msgid, data
            FROM network.flows
            """)
data.take(1)
```

I get an error which begins as follows:

```
An error occurred while calling o418.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 68, abc.abc.com, executor 28): org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file hdfs://nameservice1/data/base/db/file_152235b0-3f1e-4c35-b0cc-710a4b8d7c66.parquet
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:223)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's JSON? If so, then I don't think `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader` would be part of the stacktrace

Comment: Can you try `spark.table("network.flows").select("msgid" , "data").show()`?

Comment: @cricket_007 in fact, no. But it is in the form of: {"timestamp": 234234, "value":234.234, "direction": true}

Comment: Where does it look like like that? If you have JSON inside of a column of parquet, then `data` should be a string, not a Struct

Comment: @cricket_007 that was my mistake, sorry. Its type is "struct" in the database.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried `spark.table("network.flows").select("msgid" , "data").show()`. It shows the frame, but the whole column "data" is null :(

Comment: Are you enabling hive support before you start the query?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. It all works well except of the fact, that all 'struct' columns are None.

Comment: In my experience, this happens when Spark fails to read that column of the table. And Spark and Hive don't share the same file readers, I've found... At least, that was with Avro files

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for the help.